# jQuery and multiple li AppendTo

Tags: jquery, list, appendto

I'm having some trouble fading in some `li` elements after being appended to a list.

*var html contains the list items.*

```
$(html).hide().appendTo('#thelist').fadeIn();
```

The fade in works when there's a single li element loaded in however if there's multiple li's jQuery doesnt insert anything let alone fade it in.

Could anyone suggest a fix?

**EDIT 1:**

Example - thelist is my ul and it's not hidden.

```
<ul id="thelist">
   <li>entry1</li>
   <li>entry2</li>
   <li>entry3</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT 2:** The list exists as above in HTML and then the jQuery adds additional li's which I wish to be faded in.

**EDIT 3:** html contains a jQuery ajax call containing the html to display around 5 li's with article content.
It adds correctly to the ul when I don't use a fade in or animate. When I add a fade in it adds the elements to the ul however it doesn't fade them in.

**EDIT 4:** Here's the load function:

```
 $(function() {
     $('.more').live('click',function() {
     var element = $(this);
     var msg = element.attr('id');
     $('#morebutton').html('<p><em>Loading Articles.</em></p>');
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'more.asp',
         data: 'lastmsg=' + msg,
         cache: false,
         success: function(html){
             $('#morebutton').remove();
             $(html).hide().appendTo('#thelist').fadeIn();
         }
     });
     });
 });
```

**SOLUTION:**

I got it to fade in by changing:

```
 $(html).hide().appendTo('#thelist').fadeIn();
```

to

```
 var item = $(html).fadeIn();
 $('#thelist').append(item);
```

Seems like it's something to do with the way jQuery chains in a particular order.

Comment: Can you provide some html and more codes of your page ?

Comment: Is '#thelist' is your ul and is it hidden because you applied hide function on html variavle (li) and trying to fadein the ul, as seems to me.

Comment: the fade in occurs on the html, not the ul, which is specified after

Comment: As per below, it does seem like this should work, can you post more of your code.  Specifically it would be good to see where html is coming from.  Is html a string with the markup in it? Or is it an actual list of DOM nodes?

Comment: What exactly, does html contain?

Comment: If you look at my jsfiddle below you'll see that the code works if the html is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try using after

```
$(html).hide().after('#thelist').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Using after will insert the li's outside of the ul :/

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Ensure your list items and list exist. Check for typos of any ids.

http://jsfiddle.net/gftdz/1/

Comment: Hi Trevor, I see that the code works there however I haven't got the same setup.

Comment: What does the html returned to the server look like?  Try added dataType: 'html', to the ajax object. Also, `console.log(html)`

Comment: Hi Trevor, I've got it to fade in now. It was nothing wrong with the HTML ajax object.

Comment: What was it? I'm just curious.

Comment: See above, i've added the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be you want something like this

```
$('#thelist').fadeOut('fast',function(){$('#thelist').append(html).fadeIn()});
```